# Parsing Date from webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services, datetime

I'm getting dates back from a webservice, and they look like this:

`/Date(1310187160270+1200)/`

How would I go about converting this to a date object in javascript?

I've googled around a bit and cannot find a decent answer - this may be in part due to the fact that I'm not exactly sure what this type of date object is called - so if someone could shed light on that also, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(1310187160270+1200); 
console.log(date)
```

returns

Sat Jul 09 2011 06:52:41 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)

If you need to strip it as is in Question:

```
var returnVariable = "/Date(1346713200000+0100)/";
var d = new Date(parseFloat(returnVariable.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "")));
```

Comment: Lol - Thats because my pc is set to South African time :). I'm assuming yours is set to New Zealand time - we're 10 hours apart

Comment: The + sign signifies the offset - so the times are the same. I'm at GMT +2, you're at GMT +12

Comment: This does not handle the offset correctly. See @Bergi's answer instead.

Comment: This treats the offset `"+1200"` as 1200 milliseconds when it's 12 hours and 0 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

As the previous answer does not handle timezone offsets, I'll throw in my version:

```
function fromDateString(str) {
    var res = str.match(/\/Date\((\d+)(?:([+-])(\d\d)(\d\d))?\)\//);
    if (res == null)
        return new Date(NaN); // or something that indicates it was not a DateString
    var time = parseInt(res[1], 10);
    if (res[2] && res[3] && res[4]) {
        var dir = res[2] == "+" ? -1 : 1,
            h = parseInt(res[3], 10),
            m = parseInt(res[4], 10);
        time += dir * (h*60+m) * 60000;
    }
    return new Date(time);
}
```

Correct result is `Fri Jul 08 2011 18:52:40 GMT+0200`, or `Fri, 08 Jul 2011 16:52:40 GMT`.