# Javascript Date from milliseconds and timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)
>   [Parsing Date from webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024367/parsing-date-from-webservice)

Sorry if this question has already been asked. I have look around but have been unable to find one. Is there a quick and convenient way to convert a "*json*" date into a human friendly format using only `javascript` and `jQuery` (excluding additional `jQuery`libraries)?

The date is format is the following:

```
creationDate: "/Date(1346713200000+0100)/"
```

Thanks

Comment: there's no such thing as a *json date*. You'll need to just strip out the additional non-digit (except `+`) chars and create a date in javascript. See this question for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024367/parsing-date-from-webservice

Comment: cant you just do: `var d=new Date(1346713200000+0100);`?

Comment: yep 

>var d = new Date(1346713200000+0100)
>d
Mon Sep 03 2012 19:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Comment: @Ahren: Is it not a given that "json" date was meant as a Javascript date? (Acronym.. JSON!).. I am just curious, what would you call it?

Answer (score 7):

```
> var maybeDateString = "/Date(1346713200000+0100)/";
> fromDateString(maybeDateString)
Tue Sep 04 2012 02:00:00 GMT+0200

function fromDateString(str) {
    var res = str.match(/\/Date\((\d+)(?:([+-])(\d\d)(\d\d))?\)\//);
    if (res == null)
        return new Date(NaN); // or something that indicates it was not a DateString
    var time = parseInt(res[1], 10);
    if (res[2] && res[3] && res[4]) {
        var dir = res[2] == "+" ? -1 : 1,
            h = parseInt(res[3], 10),
            m = parseInt(res[4], 10);
        time += dir * (h*60+m) * 60000;
    }
    return new Date(time);
}
```