# convert gregorian datetime to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a service call that returns a datetime stamp from  sql server database.  I believe its gregorian calendar.

ex `/Date(1355762048307+0000)/`

I need to display this in a more readable format like `MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss`.  How can i do this in javascript of jquery?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What problem are you having? Where are you stuck? `var d = new Date(1355762048307+0000), day = d.getDate(), mon = d.getMonth() + 1, year = d.getFullYear(); console.log(day + '/' + mon + '/' + year);` Reference: [`Date()`, at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: @DavidThomas: That does not work for other timezones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13614792/1048572) on how to parse a date string with that format to a [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12632148/1048572) on how to format it.