# missing something with my epoch date conversion

Tags: javascript, date, epoch

I'm splitting an array, when I take the middle of the array which is reporting as epoch date in milliseconds. I'm testing the date using [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com) and its valid.

I run the date() object and multiply by 1000 to adjust but I'm getting year 4000. I've switched to division just to test if I'm getting too large of a number the year is correct but the day and months are wrong....I've got to be missing something simple:

```
var jEtrim = item.DTM.split(/[(-]/);
    var date = new Date(jEtrim[1] *1000);
```

sample output: Thu Jan 08 44037 07:03:20 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

Here's the jEtrim: `["/Date", "1343151455000", "0400)/"]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Date from webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13637479/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi You could have just linked to the question you know. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) takes its argument in milliseconds already, so you will not need to multiply by 1000. You will only need to convert it to a number:

```
new Date(+"1343151455000")
```

Comment: thanks, that was it...I'm currently learning JS through the Mozilla Dev network, and googling. I hate to keep asking dumb questions if you have any other resources for learning JS I'm open to more sources.

Comment: There's an overview of different tutorials at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript. I've found [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html) to be the best one.