# JSON date with Timezone offset not converting to JavaScript Date correctly

Tags: javascript, json

I've got this following string from JSON API:

```
"Date": "\/Date(1381446000000+0100)\/",
```

which should be:

```
2013-10-11 00:00:00
```

but instead I get this:

```
2013-10-10T23:00:00.000Z
```

My code:

```
new Date(parseFloat(oldDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "")));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Date from webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024367/parsing-date-from-webservice) or [Javascript Date from milliseconds and timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614792/javascript-date-from-milliseconds-and-timezone)

Comment: Already had a look at those links and tried their solutions but none of them worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This :

```
var date = "/Date(1381446000000+0100)/";
var d = new Date(parseFloat(date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "")));
```

Comment: This answer ignores the offset so the time will be wrong unless the offset was `+0000`

Comment: @JonAdams—do you have a reference to documentation for how the offset should be treated (genuine request)? Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13637479/257182) handle it correctly?

Comment: @RobG Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13637479/2291 looks acceptable.

Comment: @JonAdams—so no documentation? I'd like to find something that looks official on how to create it or parse it. It seems to be treated as if the first number is a millisecond offset from the epoch in the source location, and that the offset is HHmm and has to be applied to get UTC. So in this case `new Date(1381446000000 - 3.6e6).toISOString()` which gives 2013-10-10T22:00:00.000Z,  Is that correct?