# How can I convert "/Date(1399739515000)/" into date format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My C# server side code is using listJson, it generates time strings like this:

`"CaptureTime":"/Date(1399739515000)/"`

How to convert into date format in JavaScript client side?

Comment: You probably don't want to use MS JSON serializers in the first place. http://james.newtonking.com/json is pretty much .NeT de-facto json serializer nowadays.

Comment: Consult this article:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

And consider using JSON.NET, as Steve mentioned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Date from webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13637479/1048572)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format a Microsoft JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/206384/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real short hand:

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
     var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
     var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
     var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
     return yyyy + '-' + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-' + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
};

var s='/Date(1399739515000)/';
var regex = /(\d+)/g;
alert(new Date(parseInt(s.match(regex))).yyyymmdd());
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
<script>
d = new Date(1399739515000)
</script>
```

then d will be a javascript variable that you can then manipulate it on your scripts,
like this code for example

```
d.toUTCString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @fedmich:

```
var s='/Date(1399739515000)/';
var r=/\/Date\((\d*?)\)\//.exec(s);
var d=new Date(parseInt(matches[1]));
console.log(d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDate());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/walkingp/7cA9p/

Comment: Cool :) Mark your answer up as your selected answer then